# How to find rows for which another related row does not exist

Tags: sql, exists

I have a table that consists of an invoice number and a transaction code. A single invoice can contain transaction code of 10 and 11:

```
+------------------+-----------------+
| Transaction Code |  Invoice Number |
+------------------+-----------------+
|     10           |   CAN000700798  |
|     20           |   CAN000700798  |
+------------------+-----------------+
```

It is possible for an invoice to only contain a record with a transaction code of 10:

```
+------------------+-----------------+
| Transaction Code |  Invoice Number |
+------------------+-----------------+
|     10           |   CAN000700798  |
+------------------+-----------------+
```

Example of invoice table showing both cases:

```
+------------------+-----------------+
| Transaction Code |  Invoice Number |
+------------------+-----------------+
|     10           |   CAN000700798  |
+------------------+-----------------+ 
|     10           |   CAN000900999  |
|     20           |   CAN000900999  |
+------------------+-----------------+ 
|     10           |   CAN000700777  |
|     20           |   CAN000700777  |
+------------------+-----------------+
```

This is what I would expect from the query on the invoice table; since invoice CAN000700798 only contains a transaction code 10 and not a 10 and a 20.

```
+------------------+-----------------+
| Transaction Code |  Invoice Number |
+------------------+-----------------+
|     10           |   CAN000700798  |
+------------------+-----------------+
```

I need to write a query that looks at the invoices and checks if it contains both records having a transaction code 10 and 11. If the invoice only contains transaction code 10, return the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, MIN(TransactionCode) AS TransactionCode
FROM t
GROUP BY InvoiceNumber
HAVING MIN(TransactionCode) = 10
AND    MAX(TransactionCode) = 10
```

Comment: this provided the result i was expecting.  Thank you. Looking at what i tried earlier, i missed HAVING clause so was not returning the result, but yours has worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try if the following query is suitable for you:

```
SELECT T.TransactionCode, T.InvoiceNumber
FROM InvoiceTable AS T
WHERE T.TransactionCode = 10 AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM InvoiceTable AS X
    WHERE X.InvoiceNumber = T.InvoiceNumber AND X.TransactionCode <> 10
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however this did not yield the result I was after.  I tried this with my table inputs and when i ran it and returned the invoices - i checked the database and the invoices contained both transaction code 10 & 20.

Comment: Small typo fixed. Yes, it gets confusing inside sub queries.

Comment: @SalmanA - yes this amended query also works.  Thank you for reviewing and making the adjustments. I can see where you had to make the changes to make this work.